# How to Get All Thread Details , Like ThreadId , Description , Status . Win32 API C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, winapi

I need to get thread details like , All ThreadID , Thread Description , Thread Status.

```
         int ThrdID = osGetThreadID();
         printf(chex(mOSThreadID));
         printf(chex(getThreadDescr()));
```

Tried the above code but not getting anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enumerate running threads using [`CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/nf-tlhelp32-createtoolhelp32snapshot) with [`Thread32First()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/nf-tlhelp32-thread32first)/[`Thread32Next()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/nf-tlhelp32-thread32next) (see [Traversing the Thread List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/toolhelp/traversing-the-thread-list) on MSDN).

Most threads are not assigned a description at runtime.  But, for those that are, they can have their descriptions assigned in one of two possible ways (see [Set a Thread Name in Native Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-set-a-thread-name-in-native-code?view=vs-2019) on MSDN):

- On Windows 10 v1607 and Windows Server 2016 onward, by calling [`SetThreadDescription()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-setthreaddescription).  You can query such a description by using [`OpenThread(THREAD_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openthread) and [`GetThreadDescription()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getthreaddescription).
- by throwing a special `MS_VC_EXCEPTION` (0x406D1388) exception via `RaiseException()`, which a debugger attached to the calling process can catch and cache for its own use.  There is no API available to query these descriptions.

Comment: Thanks . Please share if you have any examples

Comment: @AravindanSrinivasan there are code examples in the various links I provided.